# Masking json response payload

Tags: json, rest, response, masking, payload

I want to know how can we create a REGEX to mask below value of content against Created By key in response received from REST API.

```
\\\"CreatedBy\\\":{\\\"content\\\":\\\"abcd@test.com\\\"}
```

So output which I am expecting is
`\\\"CreatedBy\\\":{\\\"content\\\":\\\"****@****.***\\\"}` OR
`\\\"CreatedBy\\\":{\\\"content\\\":\\\"*************\\\"}` which is getting logged in output logs.

The one which I created by taking reference of other

```
(?<=\\\\"CreatedBy\\\\": \s*{\\\\"content\\\\":\\\ "*)
```

but this is not working, can anybody help me on this

Comment: Is there a specific reason the response is escaped? I feel like getting proper JSON returned would be a better alternative, then you can parse/replace individual fields. Also, regex only finds text, not replaces/masks

Comment: reason is response contains PII data, which we want to mask, here i have posted with test email address

Comment: That doesn't answer why there's a bunch of backslashes within what's seemingly JSON. And still, regex isn't what you want